# pairwise similarity comparison matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, similarity

I have a matrix A containing events and the related probability that they occours.
for example

```
A= [1, 0.6; 5, 0.3; 4, 0.1]
```

event 1 occours with a probability of 60%, event 5 with 30% and event 4 with 1%.

Then I have a series of similar matrices (events-probabilities)

```
B = [1,0.5; 3,0.4; 2,0.1]
C = [2,0.9; 4,0.1; 3,0]
D = [1,0.6; 5,0.3; 4,0.1]
```

and I would like to find a vector showing the similarity of A with each of the others matrices.

```
SIM = [?,?,1]
```

the first 2 elements contains the similarity between A and B and between A and C.
The 3rd element shows the similarity between A and D (1 because they are the same).

Do you have any suggestion on how to implement the function to do the pairwise comparisons between the matrices?

Thanks a lot!!!

please consider also the case where A is
`A = [3,1;5,0;2,0]` (that would be equal to have `A=[3,1;2,0;1,0]` etc...)

Comment: What similarity metric will you use? RSME? absolute difference?

Comment: I edited my question to give a more generic example...

Comment: So the problem is you need to order each set of rows so that the corresponding events line up?  If we can assume that all conditions appear in all the distributions, we wouldn't need the first column at all - just keep something like `[Avals, Aix] = sort(A(:,1)); Aprobs = A(Aix,2)`, then compare Aprobs, Bprobs etc. with something like `pdist([Aprobs';Bprobs';Cprobs';Dprobs])`

Comment: Just a syntax correction: maybe you'd want you matrices like `B = [1,0.5; 3,0.4; 2,0.1]` (otherwise you'll get `cat` errors)

Comment: @dpwe thanks for your answer, but what do you mean with "If we can assume that all conditions appear in all the distributions"..what is a condition for you?

Comment: How come it doesn't matter which similarty measure you use? You need to define that first

Comment: @LuisMendo Hi Luis, yes you are right...I am not sure about the right similarity function to use...I think that the euclidean distance would work, but if I have matrix with more than 3 events (say 20) then it could not be the right choice....do you have any suggestion?

Comment: no actually the euclidean distance is a bad choice...I need something that takes into account that 2 matrices that contain different events are less similar than 2 matrices that contains the same events but with different (also very different) probabilities

Comment: @gabboshow It depends on the application. Correlation distance (one of the options of [pdist](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist.html)) at least has the advantage that it's normalized

Comment: What I call conditions is what you call events. Thus, each matrix will have the same number of rows, with the same set of values in the first column.  Else you can canonicalize them with something like Acanonical(A(:,1)) = A(:,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function for similarity calculation between `A` and `B`

```
function SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)

%// Get joint unique events for A and B
unq_events = unique([A(:,1);B(:,1)]).'; %//'

%// Presence of events across joint unique events
event_tagA = bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),unq_events);
event_tagB = bsxfun(@eq,B(:,1),unq_events);

%// Probabilities corresponding to each joint event
tagged_probA = sum(bsxfun(@times,A(:,2),event_tagA));
tagged_probB = sum(bsxfun(@times,B(:,2),event_tagB));

%// Set not-shared events as NaN
tagged_probA(~any(event_tagA))=nan;
tagged_probB(~any(event_tagB))=nan;

%// Get the similarity factors for each shared event. This is based on the
%// assumption that probabilities far apart must have a low shared
%// similarity factor. This factor would be later on used to scale the
%// individual probabilties for A and B.
sim_factor = 1-abs(tagged_probA-tagged_probB);
tagged_probA_sim_scaled = tagged_probA.*sim_factor;
tagged_probB_sim_scaled = tagged_probB.*sim_factor;

%// Get a concatenated matrix of scaled probabilities
tagged_probAB_sim_scaled = [tagged_probA_sim_scaled;tagged_probB_sim_scaled];

%// Get a hybrid array of probabilities based on the mean of probabilities
%// across A and B. Notice that for cases with identical probabilities, the
%// hybrid values would stay the same.
hybrid_probAB = mean(tagged_probAB_sim_scaled);

%// Get the sum of hybrid values. Notice that the sum would result in a
%// value of 1 when we have identical probabilities for identical events
SIM = nansum(hybrid_probAB);

return;
```

---

## Sample inputs to test out the similarity calculations

```
%// Case 1 - First exammple from the question with D replacing B.
%// The SIM value must be 1 as mentioned in the question
disp('------------- Case 1 -----------------')
A= [1, 0.6; 5, 0.3; 4, 0.1]
B = [1,0.6; 5,0.3; 4,0.1]
SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)

%// Case 2 - Slight change to the first example with event 5 being
%// replaced by event 2 in B
%// The SIM value must be lesser than 1 as mentioned in the question
disp('------------- Case 2 -----------------')
A= [1, 0.6; 5, 0.3; 4, 0.1]
B = [1,0.6; 2,0.3; 4,0.1]
SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)

%// Case 3 - As presented in the comments by OP, that the SIM value must be 0
disp('------------- Case 3 -----------------')
A =[3,1;2,0;1,0]
B =[2,1;1,0;4,0]
SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)

%// Case 4 - As asked by me and replied by OP that SIM must be 1
disp('------------- Case 4 -----------------')
A =[3,1;2,0;1,0]
B =[3,1;2,0;1,0]
SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)

%// Case 5 - Random case added on my own.
%// As can be seen event 3 is common between A and B. Apart from event3,
%// only event 2 is common, but the probabilities arew far apart, so the
%// net SIM value must be slightly more than the identical probability of
%// event 3, i.e. slightly more than 0.55
 disp('------------- Case 5 -----------------')
A =[3,0.55;2,0.95;1,0]
B =[3,0.55;2,0.05;4,0.4]
SIM = SIMcalc(A,B)
```

## Results

```
------------- Case 1 -----------------
A =
    1.0000    0.6000
    5.0000    0.3000
    4.0000    0.1000
B =
    1.0000    0.6000
    5.0000    0.3000
    4.0000    0.1000
SIM =
     1
------------- Case 2 -----------------
A =
    1.0000    0.6000
    5.0000    0.3000
    4.0000    0.1000
B =
    1.0000    0.6000
    2.0000    0.3000
    4.0000    0.1000
SIM =
    0.7000
------------- Case 3 -----------------
A =
     3     1
     2     0
     1     0
B =
     2     1
     1     0
     4     0
SIM =
     0
------------- Case 4 -----------------
A =
     3     1
     2     0
     1     0
B =
     3     1
     2     0
     1     0
SIM =
     1
------------- Case 5 -----------------
A =
    3.0000    0.5500
    2.0000    0.9500
    1.0000         0
B =
    3.0000    0.5500
    2.0000    0.0500
    4.0000    0.4000
SIM =
    0.6000
```

## Explanation

Let's take `case 5` to explain in detail the underlying principle that decides on the final scalar value that measures the similarity between `A` and `B`. It is suggested to run the code for this case and watch the values of the variables.

**Inputs**

```
A =
    3.0000    0.5500
    2.0000    0.9500
    1.0000         0
B =
    3.0000    0.5500
    2.0000    0.0500
    4.0000    0.4000
```

**Step 1**

Tag the probabilities for `A` and `B` corresponding to their events, so that the events that are not common are put as `NaNs`. Thus, we would have `tagged_probA` and `tagged_probB` and their values are shown below -

```
Event 1  Event 2  Event 3  Event 4
   0      0.95     0.55     NaN
  NaN     0.05     0.55     0.4
```

**Step 2**

Calculate the difference between the probabilities and then subtract the result from `1`. Thus, a number closer to `1` would mean degree of similarity. For example, in this example for `event 3`, we would have the result as `1`. This forms the basis of finding the similarity criteria between `A` and `B`, because we are getting `1` for identical probabilities and lesser values as the probabilities are far apart on the scale of `[0 1]`. This is stored into `sim_factor` –

```
sim_factor =
       NaN    0.1000    1.0000       NaN
```

**Step 3**

Scale the tagged probabilities for `A` and `B` using `sim_factor`. Thus, we have the tagged probabilities scaled according to the similarities between `A` and `B`. These are –

```
tagged_probA_sim_scaled =
       NaN    0.0950    0.5500       NaN
tagged_probB_sim_scaled =
       NaN    0.0050    0.5500       NaN
```

**Step 4**

Since the final value is supposed to be just a scalar value, we can get the average values across the tagged and scaled probabilities. The resultant values would have the same values with as individual probabilities for identical probabilities case, as for `event 3` in this example. For the not identical cases, it would scale down the probabilities based on the dissimilarity between `A` and `B` probabilities. This is `hybrid_probAB` as shown below -

```
hybrid_probAB =
       NaN    0.0500    0.5500       NaN
```

**Step 5**

Sum the non-NaN elements from `hybrid_probAB`, to give us the final scalar similarity value, which is lesser than `1` for this specific case. It would have given us a perfect `1` for a case with identical probabilities.

## Concluding remarks

Looking at the `SIM` values, they do follow the expected trends. So, hopefully it would work out for your other cases. To calculate similarity values between `A` and other arrays, please run the function with them as inputs.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this is not totally correct...Indeed you do not consider the events...if you change D in D =[1,0.6; 2,0.3; 4,0.1] the similarity between A and D is still 1, but the event 5 and 2 are totally different. I agree with the intuition of @fyts that we should first create the "complete vectors" containing all the events..

Comment: @gabboshow But in the very last sentence of your question, you said - `'A = [3,1;5,0;2,0] (that would be equal to have A=[3,1;2,0;1,0]'`, so I assumed the events are just for namesake.

Comment: event 3 had the 100% prob to occour

Comment: please consider the case when A =[3,1;2,0;1,0] and B =[2,1;1,0;4,0]. in this case the similarity between A and B should be 0

Comment: @gabboshow If `A =[3,1;2,0;1,0] and B(same as A) = [3,1;2,0;1,0]`, what would be the SIM value? Zero or One or some other value or not sure? If you think it must be zero, what if I make very slight modification to it - `A =[3,0.98;2,0.01;1,0.01] and B(again same as A) = [3,0.98;2,0.01;1,0.01]`, what must be the SIM value now?

Comment: if A and B =[3,1;2,0;1,0] the SIM should be 1 because it means that both in A and B event 3 will occour with a probability of 100%

Comment: basically you can see A and B as matrices representing events distributions...if the event distributions are the same the similarity between A and B should be 1

Comment: @gabboshow Check out the edits! That was some work!!

Comment: thanks a lot! I read your answer and test cases and it seems be really what I was looking for...
Thanks again

Comment: your function works great but I have some difficulties in understanding it...could you explain how you compute the similarity/similarity factors? It would be great if you can write down the formula used...

Comment: ps I compared your function with the vector space model and they gives pretty much the same results...(not identical)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you.. please have a look at my previous 2 comments @Divakar

Comment: @gabboshow Added **Explanation** part for your convenience. Hope this helps you out. It's totally home-cooked method based on the requirements presented by you in the question and the comments. If there's any similarity found with any external resource, please consider that as coincidental. I am considering using this disclaimer in my future answers :)

Answer (score 0):

OK so you choose a function that takes in two matrices and outputs a scalar, that way you can just use `bsxfun`:

```
similarity = @(x,y)(mean(mean(x./y)));
M = cat(3,B,C,D); %//Combine into a single 3D matrix
squeeze(sum(mean(bsxfun(similarity, A, M),2)))
```

Note that my similarity function I used is probably not the best for your data since it returns `Inf` if the second matrix has a `0` in it and also it's not symmetrical. The point is to illustrate that it must take a 2D matrix and output a scalar.

Comment: I tried to run your code and indeed I get Error using bsxfun
Invalid output dimensions....
I am not sure that I get the point...could you explain how to use the eucledian distance

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered forming a complete probability histogram of the 5 events? Let's say:

```
Ah=[0.6 0 0 0.1 0.3];
Bh=[0.5 0.1 0.4 0 0];
Ch=[0 0.9 0 0.1 0];
Dh=[0.6 0 0 0.1 0.3];
```

Then you could compare them as vectors, concatenating them in a matrix and using pdist:

```
m=[Ah; Bh; Ch; Dh];
sim=squareform(pdist(m,'cityblock'));
```

Comment: Hi why sim is a 4x4 matrix? and what does it represent?

Comment: It is a pairwise distance matrix, for every possible couple of the rows of m. Each element sim(ii,jj) indicates the distance between the distance between ii and jj rows of m. Notice that its diagonal elements are zero (the distance of a row from itself).